# Accessing webservice reference with JSON gives no webservice found

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I've searched but couldn't find a solution yet.

When I want to access my web service "costService.asmx" with JSON, client side to update an asp:chart in real time, I get an error from JSON saying that the web service "costService" could not be found.

I've tried almost everything:
I followed this:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

That code works but when I use it with my own service it doesn't work.

I've added

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="Documentation"/>
        <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

I'm almost certain it's because I have separated my service and site as two projects. My site has a srevice reference called "CostServiceProxy" and using that server side on my site works without a problem.

so how do I make JSON use "CostServiceProxy" i.e. my service reference?

the client side code:

```
$(function () {
        //intercept the onchange event fire by element
        //with "graphType" ID (SELECT)
        $(".ddlChartType").change(function () {
            //get the attribute "value" of the OPTION
            //element selected and pass it as parameter
            getChartImage($("option:selected", this).attr("value"));
        });
    });

    function getChartImage(type) {
        if (type < 0) return;

        //create the object for passing data to Web Service
        var dataPassed = new Object();
        dataPassed.iType = type;

        //call a Web service with jQuery
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: WebServiceURL + "/DrawChart",
            data: $.toJSON(dataPassed),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) { var data = $.evalJSON(msg).d; $("#ChartArea").attr("src", data); },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText); }
        });
    }
```

Server side I do:

```
CostServiceProxy.CostServiceSoapClient client = new CostServiceProxy.CostServiceSoapClient();
```

To use the methodes and objects from the service.

**Edit**

My WebService class:

```
namespace CostService {
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CostService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
//To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class CostService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
```

My methode in that class:

```
[WebMethod]
public String DrawChart(Int32 iType, double CostToRender) {
```

When I look under the Net tab of firebig I see the following:
[image: 500 internal server error POST DrawChart]
**Edit II**

I've gotten it to work on my site by putting the methode on my default.aspx code behind. It still has some imperfections, but the chart with the data gets shown.
I will now try and see if it works when I change the url to that of the webservice.

Comment: Check the header return values from your service (via, for instance, Firebug's Network panel) and make sure it is returning `Content-Type: text/javascript`. The ajax call (although I prefer `$.getJSON()`) will fail if it is the wrong content type.

Comment: Is your web service decorated with the `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` decorator? Normally, when you first create the service, it is commented out. Your class requires this decorator in order to be called from script.

Comment: I overlooked that comment part but I added that manually already and it still didn't work.

What about the fact that I I have it as a separate project?

Comment: The project location would make no difference to your JavaScript unless your separate project is not loaded and running in Casini at the time you're debugging.

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error when I look under the tab Net in firebug at the URL "POST DrawChart", it's Response header:
X-AspNet-Version2.0.50727
Cache-Control private
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8

request header:
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: This is really starting to get on my nerves, Since I don't have time I decided to just do it on client. So I added the methode drawChart on my default.aspx page so JSON should be able to get it like this: "default.aspx/DrawChart" But even that simple thing doesn't work!

Now I get an unknow web methode error

Comment: Ok I got it to work in my client but that has to be public static so I don't know how I can save it to a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't modified your service at all, the first thing you'll need to do is make sure that the service class is decorated with the `[ScriptService]` attribute. That's what enables it to respond with JSON if you POST to it with a Content-Type of `application/json`. Without that attribute, you'll only get XML out (and it won't know how to interpret that JSON parameter string you're POSTing in either).